# Powerpoint in 3/4 of the screen

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

Is there a way to show a powerpoint presentation with black borders all around without changing the presentation?

Some of our screens are now wide and will cut off the top and bottom of the presentation. It's fine for presenters who know about it - they can plan their presentations accordingly, but for people who don't know, we need a quick way to fix their presentations.

We do have multiple graphics cards in the computer (a total of 4 outputs), so if there is a way to show the same presentation on more than one screen at a time (+ presenter view which we always use) that would be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint can correct for this if you have the resolution of the desktop set accordingly.  Such as if you set the desktop to a widescreen resolution powerpoint will scale accordingly.

Comment: The signal is narrow screen. The screens cut the top and bottom of the signal away where appropriate (some of the screens are not wide and they all get the same signal).

Answer (score 1):

Often you can fix this by just changing the resolution on the computer. It seems to me that the projector is expecting a specific resolution, if the computer is set to output that, it should scale fine!

Alternatively, PowerPoint has a lot of features for customizing how the presentation is shown. I doubt these features are new to 07, but since that's the version I'm running... in the ribbon tabs click on "Slide Show" and then try either changing the resolution or try messing with "Use Presenter View". Maybe one of those could help?